# Kotlin Native Initialize Array of Struct

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

In Kotlin/Native, what is the correct way to create and initialize an array of a structure? My code interfaces with a C library that defines the relevant structures as:

```c
typedef struct VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo {
    ...
} VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo;

typedef struct VkDeviceCreateInfo {
    ...
    uint32_t                       queueCreateInfoCount;
    const VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo* pQueueCreateInfos;
    ...
} VkDeviceCreateInfo;
```

I've created wrapper classes `DeviceQueueCreateInfo` and `DeviceCreateInfo`. The Kotlin bindings are generated as classes inheriting from `CStructVar` and used like this:

```kotlin
class DeviceQueueCreateInfo(...) {
    // Allocates in `scope` and fills a `VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo`
    fun toRaw(scope: MemScope): VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo = ...
}

class DeviceCreateInfo(val queueCreateInfos: List<DeviceQueueCreateInfo>) {
    // Allocates in `scope` and fills a `VkDeviceCreateInfo`
    fun toRaw(scope: MemScope) = with(scope) {
        alloc<VkDeviceCreateInfo>().also {
            it.queueCreateInfoCount = queueCreateInfos.size.toUInt()
            it.pQueueCreateInfos = ??? // Allocate array of struct in `scope`
        }
    }
}
```

I've added a `???` to the code to show where I'm having trouble. Kotlin `NativePlacement` has `allocArray<T>(length: Int)`, so that was obviously my first stop:

```kotlin
it.pQueueCreateInfos = allocArray(queueCreateInfos.size)
```

And then to initialize them I tried:

```kotlin
it.pQueueCreateInfos = allocArray<VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo>(queueCreateInfos.size)
    .also { arr ->
        queueCreateInfos.forEachIndexed { index, x -> arr[index] = x.toRaw(scope) }
    }
```

However, this fails to compile with error `No set method providing array access` at `arr[index] = x`. I wrote the following code which compiles and runs as expected:

```kotlin
val floats = listOf(1f, 2f, 3f)
allocArray<FloatVar>(floats.size).also { arr ->
    floats.forEachIndexed { index, x -> arr[index] = x }
}
```

The code is identical apart from the type used, leading me to believe that I was perhaps trying to assign to an rvalue. I went looking for `VkDeviceQueueCreateInfoVar` only to find [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-c-interop.html#bindings):

> Also, any C type has the Kotlin type representing the lvalue of this type, i.e., the value located in memory rather than a simple immutable self-contained value. Think C++ references, as a similar concept. For structs (and typedefs to structs) this representation is the main one and has the same name as the struct itself, for Kotlin enums it is named ${type}Var, for CPointer it is CPointerVar, and for most other types it is ${type}Var.

This states that for structs, the lvalue representation has the same name as the struct (no `Var` suffix)... so `VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo` should represent an assignable lvalue, and I'm confused as to why I am unable to assign values to my array. It occurs to me that Kotlin's assignment does something very different to a C assignment, but I had assumed there would be an idiomatic way to perform a structure assignment.

I've looked through the other overloads and methods in `NativePlacement` to find one that allows me to initialize the values in the newly created array, and I found `allocArray<T>(length: Long, initializer: T.(index: Long)->Unit)`, but this seems to suffer from the same problem.

How do I allocate and initialize an array of structures through cinterop?

Comment: It's sad that Kotlin/Native questions rarely get answers.